# Custom view to mask a parent and make transparent circle at center of parent

Tags: android, android-custom-view, surfaceview, android-framelayout

I want to make a circular suface view (porthole effect). Surface view is inside a Frame layout. I want to make a custom view that i can add to Frame layout on top of surface view and mask whole Frame layout to produce porthole effect so that surface view will be shown as circle.

I searched and a lot for answer on Web and Stackoverflow but failed.
Then i saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763696/how-to-create-a-transparent-circle-inside-rectangle-shape-in-xml-in-android/36764393#36764393) question and i tried this custom view to mask frame layout(and hence surfaceview) but i am not getting the desired result.

What i want is a custom view that can take height and width of it's parent (parent is square in shape) and make a transparent circle at it's center touching  all four sides at middle of the boundaries, rest(view - circle) of the view will be of color that i can set.

```
public class FocusView extends View {

private Paint mTransparentPaint;
private Paint mSemiBlackPaint;
private Path mPath = new Path();

public static float radius , xCor , yCor;

public FocusView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initPaints();
}

public FocusView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initPaints();
}

public FocusView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initPaints();
}

private void initPaints() {
    mTransparentPaint = new Paint();
    mTransparentPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mTransparentPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    mSemiBlackPaint = new Paint();
    mSemiBlackPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mSemiBlackPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    mPath.reset();

    mPath.addCircle(xCor,yCor,radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    mPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);

    canvas.drawCircle(xCor,yCor,radius, mTransparentPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mSemiBlackPaint);
    canvas.clipPath(mPath);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));        //A6000000
}

}
```

Please if somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will this help you? Keep in mind it is all xml no java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972667/how-to-create-a-complete-round-linearlayout-or-relativelayout/46972897#46972897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a view that paints the whole view pink and cuts a centered, circular hole making the parent visible:

```
public class FocusView extends View {

    private Paint mCutPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mInternalCanvas;

    public FocusView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public FocusView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FocusView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mCutPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        if (mInternalCanvas != null) {
            mInternalCanvas.setBitmap(null);
            mInternalCanvas = null;
        }

        if (mBitmap != null) {
            mBitmap.recycle();
            mBitmap = null;
        }

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mInternalCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mInternalCanvas == null || mBitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        final int width = getWidth();
        final int height = getHeight();

        // make the radius as large as possible within the view bounds
        final int radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        mInternalCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFF00FF);
        mInternalCanvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, mCutPaint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

The reason for drawing to an internal `Bitmap` first is that if you apply `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` to the original `Canvas` it will cut away everything that's been previously drawn to the canvas, including the parent view.

There may be better solutions out there, but this one is simple enough to understand.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the use of  **mInternalCanvas** ?

Comment: `mInternalCanvas` is used to draw to the temporary Bitmap. If you were to use `mCutPaint` on the Canvas given to `onDraw` you  you would cut out everything that was drawn before the view, so you would also cut a hole in the parent, resulting in a black circle instead of a cut through to the parent. However if you first draw to your own Canvas you can safely cut through the whole thing, and then just draw the result to the Canvas provided by `onDraw`. I hope that clears it up otherwise you can just try to apply the draw commands to the original canvas and see for your self what happens :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks again